# Rails STI class auto initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I'm trying to make a STI Base model which changes automatically to inherited class like that:

```
#models/source/base.rb
class Source::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :detect_type

  private
  def detect_type
    if (/(rss)$/ ~= self.url)
      self.type = 'Source::RSS'
    end
  end
end

#models/source/rss.rb
class Source::RSS < Source::Base
  def get_content
    puts 'Got content from RSS'
  end
end
```

And i want such behavior:

```
s = Source::Base.new(:url => 'http://stackoverflow.com/rss')
s.get_content #=> Got content from RSS

s2 = Source::Base.first # url is also ending rss
s2.get_content #=> Got content from RSS
```

Comment: I know there is a method **becomes** which may be used as self.becomes(Source::RSS) or anything else, but how to use it while initializing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would add a class method that returns the right instance.

```
class Source::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.new_by_url(params)
    type = if (/(rss)$/ ~= params[:url])
      'Source::RSS'
    end
    raise 'invalid type' unless type
    type.constantize.new(params)
  end
end
```

Then you will get the behavior needed:

```
s = Source::Base.new_by_url(:url => 'http://stackoverflow.com/rss')
s.get_content #=> Got content from RSS
```

And `s` will be an instance of `Source::RSS`.

Note: after read your comment about becomes: its  [code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) uses `klass.new`. And `new` is a class method. After initialize, your object is done and it is a `Source::Base`, and there are no way to change it.

Answer (score 3):

There are (at least) three ways to do this:

#### 1. Use a [Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

@Alejandro Babio's answer is a good example of this pattern. It has very few downsides, but you have to remember to always use the factory method. This can be challenging if third-party code is creating your objects.

#### 2. Override `Source::Base.new`

Ruby (for all its sins) will let you override `new`.

```
class Source::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.new(attributes)
    base = super
    return base if base.type == base.real_type
    base.becomes(base.real_type)
  end

  def real_type
    # type detection logic
  end
end
```

This is "magic", with all of the super cool and super confusing baggage that can bring.

#### 3. Wrap `becomes` in a conversion method

```
class Source::Base < ActiveRecord::Base
  def become_real_type
    return self if self.type == self.real_type
    becomes(real_type)
  end

  def real_type
    # type detection logic
  end
end

thing = Source::Base.new(params).become_real_type
```

This is very similar to the factory method, but it lets you do the conversion *after* object creation, which can be helpful if something else is creating the object.

Comment: 2. surely looks promising, but rails will actually return the super type as becomes does not change the type of the in-memory instance. try it out.

Comment: `becomes` returns a new instance of the requested class with a copy of the original instance's attributes. I've had issues where the `type` attribute isn't correctly persisted when calling `becomes` on an existing record, but since this is a new record that shouldn't come up.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), your classes could look like this:

```
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
end

class RSS < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :source, as: :content
  validates :source, :url, presence: true
end
```

When creating an instance you'd create the the source, then create and assign a concrete `content` instance, thus:

```
s = Source.create
s.content = RSS.create url: exmaple.com
```

You'd probably want to [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to keep things simpler.

Your `detect_type` logic would sit either in a controller, or a [service object](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services). It could return the correct class for the content, e.g. `return RSS if /(rss)$/ ~= self.url`.

---

With this approach you could ask for `Source.all includes: :content`, and when you load the `content` for each `Source` instance, Rails' polymorphism will instanciate it to the correct type.